# jQuery ajax check URL data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I honestly don't know what this is called or even begin how I search of it.. but is there a way I can use jQuery to get a page and fetch it's contents? Like if go to test.php?act=test and the contents of the page JUST has the words "no"... then have the text update say "no" and if it's "yes" then say "yes".

I hope I worded that correctly... (. _.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially would suggest getting an idea by reading this [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), then continue by reading [jQuery's AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).  Further readings would be [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Ajax calls. You are able to give a url in the same domain as the webpage and get its contents dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method in jQuery which will be issuing an AJAX request.